# Floating hint label in Android Studio not showing until pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to use a floating label in Android Studio and it is working sometimes and not others, the hint only shows once you click on the edit text otherwise it won't show. I would like it to show the password hint like the email one before you click it

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/EmailLayout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLbl">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailInput"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/PassLayout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/EmailLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLbl">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/passInput"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

I cannot see what is wrong with this code

Comment: that's because you're using android:inputType="textPassword" in the password edittext

Comment: please share your @style/TextLbl code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code by using below Code : (Its Workable code )

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:drawableLeft="@null"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

or you can set Hint by java on your Activity class as :

```
passwordEt.setHint("Password");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/PassLayout"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/EmailLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextLbl">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/passInput"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**in Java file:**

> PassLayout.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
>   InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Hope this help you..if you need any help you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you're using `android:inputType="textPassword"` in the password edittext. Try using:

```
android:gravity="center"

android:ellipsize="start"
```